# Passar lista genérica como parâmetro

Tags: c#, .net, lista, parâmetros, genéricos

É possível passar uma lista genérica por parâmetro?

Ex: Tenho uma `List<Pessoa>` e uma `List<object>`.

e tenho o meu método:

```
public void FaçaAlgo(List<T> lista) { }
```

Como posso fazer para que o meu método receba tanto a `List<Pessoa>` como `List<object>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Essa técnica é chamada de [Generics no .net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0x6a29h6.aspx).

Uma maneira simples seria assim:

```
// especificando o T na assinatura do método
public void FacaAlgo<T>(List<T> lista){}
```

Onde você poderia utilizar assim, por exemplo:

Supondo que o método faça isso:

```
public void FacaAlgo<T>(List<T> lista)
{
    foreach (T t in lista)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
    }
}
```

Você pode utilizar o método dessa forma:

```
List<string> listString = new List<string>();
listString.Add("String 1");
listString.Add("String 2");
listString.Add("String 3");
listString.Add("String 4");
FacaAlgo(listString);

List<object> listObject = new List<object>();
listObject.Add("Object 1");
listObject.Add("Object 2");
listObject.Add("Object 3");
listObject.Add("Object 4");
FacaAlgo(listObject);
```

Onde a saída seria a seguinte:

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
String 4
Object 1
Object 2
Object 3
Object 4
```

---

Mas essa seria a maneira simples, há outras formas, onde você pode especifica o tipo na instância da `class`:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
        public void FacaAlgo(List<T> lista)
        {
            // ...
        }
    // exemplo de utilização:
    // new MyClass<string>().FacaAlgo(listString);
}
```

---

E outra forma um pouco mais bacana e usual que você pode utilizar, é especificar tipos bases para o Generics, podendo serem `class` ou `interfaces`.

Onde dada a seguinte estrutura de classes:

```
public class TipoBase
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public virtual string PrintValue()
    {
        return "O valor na class TipoBase é: " + Value;
    }
}

public class Tipo1 : TipoBase
{
    public override string PrintValue()
    {
        return "O valor na class Tipo1 é: " + Value;
    }
}

public class Tipo2 : TipoBase
{
    public override string PrintValue()
    {
        return "O valor na class Tipo2 é: " + Value;
    }
}
```

Podemos implementar o seguinte método:

```
public void FacaAlgoComTipoBase<T>(List<T> lista) where T : TipoBase
{
    foreach (T t in lista)
    {
        // assim eu posso chamar o método PrintValue(), garantido pela class TipoBase
        Console.WriteLine(t.PrintValue());
    }
}
```

É possível utiliza-lo da seguinte forma, por exemplo:

```
List<TipoBase> listTipoBase = new List<TipoBase>(); 
listTipoBase.Add(new TipoBase(){Value = 1});
listTipoBase.Add(new TipoBase() { Value = 2 });

List<Tipo1> listTipo1 = new List<Tipo1>();
listTipoBase.Add(new Tipo1() { Value = 1 });
listTipoBase.Add(new Tipo1() { Value = 2 });

List<Tipo2> listTipo2 = new List<Tipo2>();
listTipoBase.Add(new Tipo2() { Value = 1 });
listTipoBase.Add(new Tipo2() { Value = 2 });

FacaAlgoComTipoBase(listTipoBase);
FacaAlgoComTipoBase(listTipo1);
FacaAlgoComTipoBase(listTipo2);
```

Onde a saída seria isso:

```
O valor na class TipoBase é: 1
O valor na class TipoBase é: 2
O valor na class Tipo1 é: 1
O valor na class Tipo1 é: 2
O valor na class Tipo2 é: 1
O valor na class Tipo2 é: 2
```

> [Exemplo online .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YXUyT0)

Answer (score 7):

Você pode utilizar Generics:

Em um método a sintaxe é a seguinte:

```
public void FacaAlgo<T>(List<T> lista){}
```

Para uma classe voce utiliza algo como:

```
public class Classe<T>
{
    public void FacaAlgo(List<T> lista)
}
```

O legal é que você pode trabalhar com interfaces e classes abstratas para definir contratos, por exemplo:

```
public inteface IParaFazer
{
    void Executar();
}

public classe Classe2<T> where T : IParaFazer
{
    public void FacaAlgo(List<T> lista)
    {
        foreach(IParaFazer obj in lista)
        {
            obj.Executar();
        } 
    }
}
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação do .NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/512aeb7t.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0x6a29h6.aspx